Android Studio Emulator strange behavior with VPN (cisco anyconnect)
community,
Got strange issue regarding Android Emulator. Here is the scene:

Windows computer with enabled Cisco Anyconnect (to organization);
Android Studio emulator with custom react-native app;

What we get:

If i open chrome in emulator and try to access http://some-my-org.url it opens as charm;
If i use fetch api in my app to fetch that same url it results with network error;

Any help appreciated, broke my mind on where to dig next.
I tried:

Disable firewalls;
Use local proxies in android studio;
Play with AnnyConnect settings checkboxes;

What am i missing here?
Thanks in advance!
